# Salesforce1: Open current object in safari browser with login

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, ios, browser

We are developing mobile friendly visualforce page. Due to the UIWebview issues with iOS7.0/7.1 there are some components which does not work as expected. Though 7.1 update fixed a lot of issue, still there are some few issues; the same code is working in iOS safari browser.

The question: Is there a way to open current page (whatever the object/custom vf) in  safari (external app) browser from salesforce1?

The opposite of `com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={Account.Id}` which open salesforce1 app from safari.

Also, I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require the user to key-in their username and password again. I have used [Frontdoor.jsp](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/security_frontdoorjsp.htm) (`frontdoor.jsp?sid=session_ID&retURL=optional_relative_url_to_open`) in the past from my custom app, looking for same with salesforce1.

Answer (score 1):

In the Frootdoor.jsp argument `optional_relative_url_to_open` try something like:

> /one/one.app?{Account.Id}

You will need to encode it as applicable for a query string parameter

---

According to [Visualforce in Salesforce1](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/visualforce-in-salesforce1.html) by Bob Buzzard using the JavaScript function  `window.open` will break out of the Salesforce1 app.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not open safari from salesforce1 as expected. It is opening within salesforce1 app.

Comment: I don't have an iOS device to test with or experience with xcode (is that correct?). How are you opening the link? What happens if you try and open a completely unrelated URL, like www.google.com?

Comment: Opening link from their pages say account website open the site in a new window. 

But I can't able to open frontdoor.jsp from vf page (ref. https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/11244749)

Also are you asking whether i have device and iOS knowledge? as a matter of fact, I have.

Comment: I'm saying I do not have an Apple device to test it out on. Using the JavaScript `window.open` function may work according to the linked blog post.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Btw, I have tried the `window.open` it is opening a child browser within salesforce1. It does not open safari. Thank you.